# I need a screen Reminder when application is off sample screen image like this

Tags: android, notifications, reminders

[image: I need a screen reminder like this if any library please suggest me]

```
 public NotificationCompat.Builder buildLocalNotification(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent, AppointmentModel appointmentModel) {
    String channelId = "Appoinment Reminder";
    Log.e("@@ChannelId", channelId);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Appoinment Reminder")
            .setContentText("Your appointment with "+appointmentModel.getContact() +" at "+ appointmentModel.getDate1()+" "+appointmentModel.getTime())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "Appoinment Reminder", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    manager.notify(NotificationID.getID(), builder.build());
    return builder;
}

 intentToRepeat.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, NotificationID.getID(),  new Intent[] {backIntent, intentToRepeat}, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            buildLocalNotification(context, pendingIntent, appointmentModelList.get(i)).build();
```

above code is working for notification but no idea about on-screen reminder

```
 WindowManager windowManager2 = (WindowManager) App.getAppContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) App.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.window_popup_medicine, null);
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams
                         params= null;
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                                   PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                        }

                        params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
                        params.x=0;
                        params.y=0;
                        windowManager2.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: I need a reminder like this as I have shared an image

Comment: You need to create an Overlay to achieve that. Use a foreground service and add a view via the windowManager.

Comment: please check window manager code

Comment: it is giving error .....    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: are you using that in a foreground service?

Comment: It is in Alarm Receiver class.

Comment: public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
}